# Bootstrap Modal popup and Django

Tags: html, django, django-forms

I'm new to django/bootstrap and currently i'm practising by using an html/css/js template which i downloaded from the internet. I rendered the template with django successfully by following a tutorial. Now i want to configure Login/Register to learn Django authentication.
Now when i press Login/Register button (picture1) a popup is displayed. I tried to render loginregister page.

```
<li class="list-inline-item list_s"><a href="{% url 'loginregister' %}" class="btn flaticon-user" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg"> <span class="dn-lg">Login/Register</span>
```

[image: Picture1]

I've created a views.py file, configured the urls.py file and created an html file in order to display my page and not the popup but unsuccessfully the popup is always displayed. I've configured the following:

index.html file

```
            <!-- Responsive Menu Structure-->
            <!--Note: declare the Menu style in the data-menu-style="horizontal" (options: horizontal, vertical, accordion) -->
            <ul id="respMenu" class="ace-responsive-menu text-right" data-menu-style="horizontal">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><span class="title">Manage Property</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><span class="title">Blog</span></a>
                        </li>
              <li class="last">
                <a href="{% url 'contact' %}"><span class="title">Contact</span></a>
              </li>
            <li class="list-inline-item list_s"><a href="{% url 'loginregister' %}" class="btn flaticon-user" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg"> <span class="dn-lg">Login/Register</span></a></li>
            <li class="list-inline-item add_listing"><a href="#"><span class="flaticon-plus"></span><span class="dn-lg"> Create Listing</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
<!-- Main Header Nav Ends -->

<!-- Login/Register Starts -->
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="sign_up_modal modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body container pb20">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <ul class="sign_up_tab nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Login</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Register</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Login Starts -->
                <div class="tab-content container" id="myTabContent">
                    <div class="row mt25 tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
                            <div class="login_thumb">
                                <img class="img-fluid w100" src="{% static 'images/resource/login.jpg' %}" alt="login.jpg">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
                            <div class="login_form">
                                <form action="#">
                                    <div class="heading">
                                        <h4>Login</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row mt25">
                                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-fb btn-block"><i class="fa fa-facebook float-left mt5"></i> Login with Facebook</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-googl btn-block"><i class="fa fa-google float-left mt5"></i> Login with Google</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect


def loginregister(request):
    return render(request, 'accounts/loginregister.html')


def login(request):
    return render(request, 'accounts/login.html')


def register(request):
    return render(request, 'accounts/register.html')


def logout(request):
    return redirect('index')
```

urls.py file

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

    urlpatterns = [
        path('loginregister', views.loginregister, name='loginregister'),
        path('login', views.login, name='login'),
        path('register', views.register, name='register'),
        path('logout', views.logout, name='logout'),
```